# jQuery selector not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this code:

```
alert (panes.selector); //gives me .css-panes .pane

var size = $(panes.selector).size(); 
alert (size); //gives me 0, confused I run the selector itself

var size = $(".css-panes .pane").size();
alert (size); //gives me 1 which is what I expect
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

**SOLVED.**
Accidental (typo) use of `panes` instead of `pane` in the actual html. 
Sorry to everyone who spent time figuring this out.

Comment: What does `$(panes.selector).selector` give you?

Comment: Could you supply a snippet of the HTML so we have some context around what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ demo please.

Comment: test to see if they are really the same selectors `alert(".css-panes .pane" == panes.selector);`

Comment: will get on all of this right now.

Comment: Sorry about this, the only problem was that I had ".panes" instead of ".pane", in the actual html. Thank you for all your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

maybe it's type conversion problem

Try:

```
var size = $(panes.selector + "").size();
```

Comment: It may be a type conversion problem though the above code did not change the value from 0 to 1. Thank you!

Comment: You can test the type of panes.selector with alert(panes.selector.constructor.name) - if it is not "String", there's your problem.